# how to know the number of feeds in an url in android

Tags: android, url, feed

in my app in have an edit box when the user types a web address it goes on and i want to calculate the number of feeds and data of the feeds in that url.

how to do this. Please help me friends

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "feeds" and "data of the feeds"?

Comment: i am asking about the RSS and Atom feeds and the content inside the tags.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to parse the XML and count for how many elements where returned.